# Unordered (hash) map from bitset to bitset on boost

Tags: c++, boost, hash, unordered-map, bitset

I want to use a cache, implemented by boost's `unordered_map`, from a `dynamic_bitset` to a `dynamic_bitset`. The problem, of course, is that there is no default hash function from the bitset. It doesn't seem to be like a conceptual problem, but I don't know how to work out the technicalities. How should I do that?

Comment: See https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/2841.

Comment: I can't use this since m.bits is a private member (the suggestion is for a change in dynamic_bitset).

Comment: m.bits should be public const, that's pretty stupid! Can you get away with using vector<bool> (which is a bitset, but one that works MUCH nicer) as the key?

Comment: I'm using a bitset since I am doing a lot of set calculations (intersections etc.), which are much much faster when done bitwise. So I guess not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found an unexpected solution. It turns out boost has an option to `#define BOOST_DYNAMIC_BITSET_DONT_USE_FRIENDS`. When this is defined, private members including `m_bits` become public (I think it's there to deal with old compilers or something).

So now I can use @KennyTM's answer, changed a bit:

```
namespace boost {
    template <typename B, typename A>
    std::size_t hash_value(const boost::dynamic_bitset<B, A>& bs) {            
        return boost::hash_value(bs.m_bits);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's `to_block_range` function that *copies* out the words that the bitset consists of into some buffer. To avoid actual copying, you could define your own "output iterator" that just processes individual words and computes hash from them.  Re. how to compute hash: see e.g. the FNV hash function.

Unfortunately, the design of `dynamic_bitset` is IMHO, braindead because it does not give you direct access to the underlying buffer (not even as `const`).

Comment: Should it be really hard to just to copy-paste the dynamic_bitset header file and replace it with "my_dynamic_bitset", where all the difference is that it's not private anymore?

Comment: It's a maintenance problem. You have to repeat the same procedure each time the mainstream file gets updated for any reason.

Answer (score 3):

It is a [feature request](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/2841).

One could implement a not-so-efficient unique hash by converting the bitset to a vector temporary:

```
namespace boost {
    template <typename B, typename A>
    std::size_t hash_value(const boost::dynamic_bitset<B, A>& bs) {
        std::vector<B, A> v;
        boost::to_block_range(bs, std::back_inserter(v));
        return boost::hash_value(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I use that? I tried "unordered_map<node_set, node_set, boost::hash<node_set> > cache;" but it still doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2):

We can't directly calculate the hash because the underlying data in `dynamic_bitset` is private (`m_bits`)

But we can easily finesse past (subvert!) the c++ access specification system without either

- hacking at the code or
- pretending your compiler is non-conforming (`BOOST_DYNAMIC_BITSET_DONT_USE_FRIENDS`)

The key is the template function `to_block_range` which is a `friend` to `dynamic_bitset`. Specialisations of this function, therefore, also have access to its private data (i.e. `m_bits`).

The resulting code couldn't be simpler

```
namespace boost {


// specialise dynamic bitset for size_t& to return the hash of the underlying data
template <>
inline void
to_block_range(const dynamic_bitset<>& b, size_t& hash_result)
{
    hash_result = boost::hash_value(bs.m_bits);
}

std::size_t hash_value(const boost::dynamic_bitset<B, A>& bs) 
{            
    size_t hash_result;
    to_block_range(bs, hash_result);
    return hash_result;
}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to be true. The specific specialization of the to_block_range function is a friend of dynamic_bitset. It is not possible to have another function by the same name with different parameters while maintaining the access of a friend function.

Comment: @BSchlinker I disagree:

`boost::dynamic_bitset` is declared as:
`template <typename Block = unsigned long,
          typename Allocator = std::allocator<Block> >
class dynamic_bitset;`

Comment: @BSchlinker:

The original _befriended_ template function is:
`template <typename B, typename A, typename BlockOutputIterator>
    friend void to_block_range(const dynamic_bitset<B, A>& b,
                               BlockOutputIterator result);`
Thus the specialisation in 
`template <> inline void to_block_range(const dynamic_bitset<>&, tuple<unsigned, unsigned,  unsigned long&>)`
means `typename B = unsigned long`, `typename A = std::allocator<Block>`, `typename BlockOutputIterator = tuple<unsigned, unsigned,  unsigned long&>`.

Looks like cheating and very naughty... but legitimate c++.

Comment: @BSchlinker. Also it compiles! (GCC 4.8 and clang 3.4)

Answer (score 0):

the proposed solution generates the same hash in the following situation.

```
#define BOOST_DYNAMIC_BITSET_DONT_USE_FRIENDS

namespace boost {
    template <typename B, typename A>
    std::size_t hash_value(const boost::dynamic_bitset<B, A>& bs) {            
        return boost::hash_value(bs.m_bits);
    }
}

boost::dynamic_biset<> test(1,false);

auto hash1 = boost::hash_value(test);

test.push_back(false);

auto hash2 = boost::hash_value(test);

// keep continue...

test.push_back(false);

auto hash31 = boost::hash_value(test);

// magically all hash1 to hash31 are the same!
```

the proposed solution is sometimes improper for hash map.

I read the source code of dynamic_bitset why this happened and realized that dynamic_bitset stores one bit per value as same as `vector<bool>`. For example, you call `dynamic_bitset<> test(1, false)`, then dynamic_bitset initially allocates 4 bytes with all zero and it holds the size of bits (in this case, size is 1). Note that if the size of bits becomes greater than 32, then it allocates 4 bytes again and push it back into `dynamic_bitsets<>::m_bits` (so m_bits is a vector of 4 byte-blocks).

If I call `test.push_back(x)`, it  sets the second bit to x and increases the size of bits to 2. If `x` is false, then `m_bits[0]` does not change at all! In order to correctly compute hash, we need to take m_num_bits in hash computation.

Then, the question is how?

1: Use `boost::hash_combine`
This approach is simple and straight forward. I did not check this compile or not.

```
namespace boost {
    template <typename B, typename A>
    std::size_t hash_value(const boost::dynamic_bitset<B, A>& bs) { 
        size_t tmp = 0;
        boost::hash_combine(tmp,bs.m_num_bits);           
        boost::hash_combine(tmp,bs.m_bits);
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

2: flip m_num_bits % bits_per_block th bit.
flip a bit based on bit size. I believe this approach is faster than 1.

```
namespace boost {
    template <typename B, typename A>
    std::size_t hash_value(const boost::dynamic_bitset<B, A>& bs) {
        // you may need more sophisticated bit shift approach.
        auto bit = 1u << (bs.m_num_bits % bs.bits_per_block);
        auto return_val = boost::hash_value(bs.m_bits);

       // sorry this was wrong
       //return (return_val & bit) ? return_val | bit : return_val & (~bit);
       return (return_val & bit) ? return_val & (~bit) : return_val | bit;
    }
}
```